# Aspose cells to read table header row

Tags: java, excel, aspose-cells

How can i retrive excel table header row.
I able to retrive all rows except table header row. 
**Code**

```
private static void printTableContent(final ListObject table) {
    System.out.println(table.getShowHeaderRow());
    Range range = table.getDataRange();

    for (int row = 0; row < range.getRowCount(); row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < range.getColumnCount(); column++) {
            System.out.print(range.get(row, column).getDisplayStringValue());
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListObject.getDataRange() will only return the data rows.

To get the header row, use ListObject.getListColumns(). Add the following code in your method to print the list of header row.

```
for (int iColumn = 0 ; iColumn < table.getListColumns().getCount() ; iColumn++)
{
    System.out.print(table.getListColumns().get(iColumn).getName());
}
System.out.println();
```

I work with Aspose as a Developer Evangelist.